# excel cells not printing

Tags: ubuntu

I have two rows in a spreadsheet that are not printing the data in the cells. The data shows up on the screen and in print preview, but when I print the sheet the cells are empty. This happened to me once before. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Have a look at [Set Print Area](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/define-or-clear-a-print-area-on-a-worksheet-HP010021542.aspx)

Comment: Are they the last rows on the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Use the table

Rather than write the data into the cells, a drawing table and then enter the data into the table.

or

> 2) Have you tried to get on another system to print?

or

> 3) Check the printer settings